# Ping hosts using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I understand that we can ping hosts with Ansible using the ping module. However, the ping module tries to ssh into the host in order to ping it. Is there a way to do this without having to ssh? Kind of like a liveness check?

Comment: The purpose of Ansible's "ping" is to verify that Ansible can interact with the host, hence SSH-ing.  What is your goal, if not that?

Comment: My goal is to be able to see if the host is reachable through ansible. I do not care about ssh-ing.

Comment: Why would you use Ansible for that? There are monitoring and testing tools readily available. Using declarative configuration management language to check network availability is like using an ambulance for firefighting. Wrong tool.

Answer (score 0):

You want to see that a port is up? Sure, you want [`wait_for`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/wait_for_module.html).

```
- name: is your fridge running?
  wait_for:
    host: 1.2.3.4 # or hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
    port: 22
    timeout: 300 # will try for 5 mins 
    state: present
```

Comment: I guess OP wants an ICMP ping. Windows-based fridges don't listen on port 22.